# AWS LEX: Webhooks subscription for callback URLhas not been accepting updates

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, webhooks, amazon-lex

When using AWS LEX to create a facebook chatbot I am now getting this error.

"Your Webhooks subscription for callback URL ############# has not been accepting updates for at least ## hour. Please verify that your callback server is functioning. Visit our reference documentation to learn how to update your callback URL. "

I have been having no problems for days then all of a sudden my bot stops responding. I deleted the Webhook from  AWS and made a new one. Then deleted the subscription from Facebook App and added it back.  When I add it back the BOT works again but only for a few requests then it stops all over again.

I can't work it out :-(

Comment: Instead of deleting something and putting it back, troubleshoot it while it's broken.  Your callback URL is not responding?  Send it a request.  See what you get.  Use `curl -v https://...`.  What happens?

Comment: Sounds like Facebook is cutting off requests to AWS Lex. Troubleshoot the connection to the endpoints for Lex and Facebook yourself as the comment about mentions